# Why is $F=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\vec{i} + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\vec{j}, (x,y)\neq 0$ not conservative?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

My book says that

$$F=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\vec{i} + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\vec{j}, (x,y)\neq 0$$

is not conservative (besides $curl(F)$ being $0$), so I cannot use the theorem that

$$\int_\gamma \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_a^b \nabla\phi(g(t))g'(t)dt =  \phi(b)-\phi(a)$$

but I can find $\phi$ such that $\nabla\phi = F$, so why this vector field cannot be conservative?

Comment: Integrate around the unit circle to find that the integral is nonzero and hence not conservative.

Comment: @FoobazJohn but the book says it before this theorem

Comment: @Foobaz John answered to your question. However, you might ask why "the theorem" does not apply in this case... :-) How about the origin?

Comment: Also, what is it you propose as $\phi$?

Comment: You claim you found a $\varphi$ so can you provide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector field $\vec{F} : \Bbb R^2 - (0, 0) \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $$\vec{F}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{bmatrix}-y\\x\end{bmatrix}$$ is indeed not conservative. If $\gamma$ is the unit circle around the origin with counterclockwise orientation, parameterize $\gamma$ as $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ with $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ and note that $$\int_\gamma \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t}\begin{bmatrix}-\sin t\\ \cos t\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}-\sin t\\ \cos t\end{bmatrix} dt = \int_0^{2\pi} dt = 2\pi$$

But we know that conservative vector fields integrate to $0$ along closed loops, thus $\vec{F}$ is not conservative. This also means any $\phi$ you have found which satisfies $\vec{\nabla \phi} = \vec{F}$ must be incorrect.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain?